# Is it possible to do a topological sort on a graph with a cycle?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, graph, topological-sort

I have this graph
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5qiqi.png)

Is it possible for me to do topological sorting with it?

Comment: Probably this question is better suited to other StackExchange communities, but if you just read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting it defines the algorithm only for directed graphs without a cycle.

Comment: You can with some algorithms, but it ends up being a (bad) approximation for [feedback arc set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feedback_arc_set).

Comment: No. You should remove edges to break the cycles. Depending on which edge(s) you remove, you'll get different topological orders.